# I need clarification on how pressure is measured

Tags: pressure, unit

I have a vessel that has a pressure measuring device. The value it shows as the pressure inside the vessel is 6 inches of water column. Is inches of water column meant to always be used as gauge pressure, or does one have to specify gauge vs atmospheric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inches of water is conventionally used as gauge pressure, not absolute.  You could conceivably specify it as inches of water absolute, but that would be an unusual use - sub-atmospheric pressures are more commonly measured in inches or mm of mercury.